# ¿Cómo evitar registros duplicados en esta consulta sobre SQL SERVER 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Una pregunta.

Como podría hacer para que la siguiente consulta no me arroje duplicados. Le he buscado y estoy algo confundido, no soy tan bueno en sql server lo aclaro. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Los duplicado me los muestra como en la imagen que adjunto..Me trae dos veces la misma clave..

Muchas gracias..

```
SELECT  
M.Clave, M.Estatus, M.Link, M.Archivo,
M.DescripcionArchivo, M.FechaRevLast,
M.ImagePath ,M.NombreArchivo, M.DeleteRel
FROM
(SELECT *, 
                   Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       partition BY Clave 
                       ORDER BY fecharevlast DESC ) AS orden 
            FROM   MotoresEmis25ene
) AS M 
WHERE Clave='930-01-DAC' AND M.orden = 1 and DeleteRel='Activado'

UNION

SELECT   
M2.Clave, M2.Estatus, M2.Link, M2.Archivo, M2.DescripcionArchivo, M2.FechaRevLast, 
M2.ImagePath, M2.NombreArchivo, M2.DeleteRel
FROM   
(SELECT *, 
                   Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       partition BY Clave 
                       ORDER BY fecharevlast DESC ) AS orden 
            FROM   MotoresEmis25ene
) AS M2
where Clave in(SELECT claverelacionada
                            FROM MotoresEmis25ene
                            where Clave='930-01-DAC'
                            and M2.DeleteRel='Activado'
                            AND M2.orden = 1
                            )
UNION

SELECT  
Clave, Estatus, Link, Archivo, DescripcionArchivo, 
FechaRevLast, ImagePath, NombreArchivo, DeleteRel
FROM 
MotoresEmis25ene
where claverelacionada ='930-01-DAC'
and DeleteRel='Activado'
group by Clave, Estatus, Link, Archivo, DescripcionArchivo, 
FechaRevLast, ImagePath, NombreArchivo, DeleteRel
ORDER BY Clave ASC, FechaRevLast DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y porque no deberia traerlo? cual de esas 3 consultas te trae el duplicado?

Comment: Hola gbianchi. Pues es lo que quiero averiguar, cual de esas tres me trae el duplicado. No deberia traerlo, porque esos datos los mostrare en un gridview y no quiero ver datos repetidos.. Tienes alguna sugerencia. Cualquiera es bienvenida.. Saludos..

Comment: Al hacer union no estás filtrando nada. No sabemos si esos resultados vienen de dos de las consultas en el union. Ya probaste cada una por separado para ver qué resultados traen?

Comment: si. proba todas por separado como dice Alfabravo... No podemos ayudarte solo mirando los querys, que estan todos correctos.. no sabemos de donde viene cada dato... no somos magos...

Comment: Lo más seguro es que sea por el último UNION. La columna FechaRevLast es distinta en las filas.

Comment: Tampoco necesitas usar GROUP BY porque UNION está eliminando duplicados.

Comment: @LuisCazares Tienes razón es el ultimo UNION. probe por separado las consultas. Pero ese dato de la FechaRevLast lo ocupo. Hay alguna forma de lograrlo?

Comment: @gbianchi UNION elimina duplicados en cualquier versión de SQL, para que no lo haga es necesario usar UNION ALL.

Comment: Si le quito la columna de FechaRevLast no me trae duplicados. Pero como te mencionaba yo necesito mostrar esa columna jeje..No se si me explico.. Y gracias por responder..

Comment: bien visto @LuisCazares... mi error...